# Matrix Rational Canonical Form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is there a way to calculate the [*Rational Canonical Form*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html) of an $n\times n$ integer matrix using *Mathematica*?

I have been perusing the documentation and web, but nothing so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem. What is needed is to factor the CharacteristicPolynomial by the MatrixMinimalPolynomial continously in order to obtain all minimal polynomials.

I did not know how to do that using one of the polynomial functions in Mathematica, so I wrote a function to do it.

### Result

This shows test matrices. The left side is the matrix, and the right side is the matrix rational form.  This function called `rationalMatrixForm` requires 2 helper functions: [companionMatrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html) and [MatrixMinimalPolynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html)

This is not optimal function by any means (uses `AppendTo` for example), and I am sure it can be improved, but first I wanted to make sure it is correct.  I tested it on number of matrices and the results agrees with [wikipdia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) and mupad results. If you find a bug in it, please let me know.

```
rationalMatrixForm[{{2, -2, 14}, {0, 3, -7}, {0, 0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[{MatrixForm[#], MatrixForm@rationalMatrixForm[#]} & /@ tests, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
CompanionMatrix[p_, x_] := Module[
  {n, w = CoefficientList[p, x]},
  w = -w/Last[w];
  n = Length[w] - 1;
  SparseArray[{{i_, n} :> w[[i]], {i_, j_} /; i == j + 1 -> 1}, {n, 
    n}]]

MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_List?MatrixQ, x_] := 
 Module[{i, n = 1, qu = {}, 
   mnm = {Flatten[IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]]}}, 
  While[Length[qu] == 0, AppendTo[mnm, Flatten[MatrixPower[a, n]]];
   qu = NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]];
   n++];
  First[qu].Table[x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]]
```

and

```
rationalMatrixForm[a_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Module[(*version 8/24/13 2PM*)
  {p, q, min, c = {}, moreFactors = True, z, x},

  p = CharacteristicPolynomial[a, x];
  min = MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a, x];

  While[moreFactors,
   q = PolynomialQuotient[p, min, x];

   If[q === 0,

    moreFactors = False;
    If[Not[FreeQ[p, x]],
     z = CompanionMatrix[p, x];
     AppendTo[c, z]
     ],

    z = CompanionMatrix[min, x];
    AppendTo[c, z];
    p = q

    ] (* if *)

   ]; (*end WHILE more factorization needed*)

  SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> c]
  ]
```

test matrices

```
 tests = {
   {{2, -2, 14}, {0, 3, -7}, {0, 0, 2}},
   {{3, 4, 0}, {-1, -3, -2}, {1, 2, 1}},
   {{-2, -1, -2, -1, 1, 0}, {-2, -1, -2, -1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
     0}, {2, 1, 0, 1, -3, -1}, {-2, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, -2, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}},
   {{0, -4, 85}, {1, 4, -30}, {0, 0, 3}},
   {{2, -2, 14, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 3, -7, 9, 20, 33}, {0, 0, 2, 9, 0, 
     3}, {2, -2, 14, 5, -8, 7}, {2, 2, 14, 23, 6, 7}, {2, 2, 14, 23, 
     6, 70}}
   };
```

Comment: Very nice, however produces an incorrect result for mat = {{2, -2, 14}, {0, 3, -7}, {0, 0, 2}}, but correct for mat = {{0, -4, 85}, {1, 4, -30}, {0, 0, 3}}. These have same characteristic polynomial, but different rational canonical forms. Regards

Comment: @Nasser: Are you saying no way to easily fix?

Comment: @Nasser: It might have to do with the fact that the first matrix in my comment has a minimal polynomial $(x-2)(x-3)$ while the second has $(x-2)^2(x-3)$, even though they both have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Nasser: Is there a way to print $P$, as in $P^{-1}AP=r$. In other words, you found $r$, but is it possible to also provide $P$?

Comment: @Amzoti I get this  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UqhSU.png)

Comment: beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Is this code correct then?

Comment: @Ryker I do not understand your question. The code is correct, unless you show otherwise. It produces the same result as on wiki, link above.

Comment: @Nasser, Amzoti was saying that it produces an incorrect result for some matrix, so I wasn't sure whether the code has been corrected then. But you're saying it has been, and that the code produces the right result for all matrices now?

Comment: @Ryker this was over a year ago. So I do not remember now. But feel free to try it, and you find a bug you can report it and will try to fix it. Make sure to include the input and the expected output to help me fix it. As far as I know the code is supposed to work ok.

Comment: @Nasser, well, I actually wanted to use the code to double check my answers, but if the issue Amzoti brought up hasn't been addressed, then I guess I can't. So my question was just trying to find out whether you acknowledged that and edited the code afterwards or not, as I couldn't tell from the discussion.

Comment: For all future readers, this code is NOT strictly correct. For example, the matrix {{0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,1},{1,1,0,1},{1,1,1,0}} has eigenvalues with $(\lambda-3)(\lambda+1)^3$. This code gives the rational canonical form as {{0, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 1, 2}}, which has eigenvalues $(\lambda-3)^2(\lambda+1)^2$, so the two matrices can't be similar. The correct RCF would be {{0, 3, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0,-1}}.